# AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient.get always returns null

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I want to retrieve data from an DynamoDB item through a Lambda function. However, the following code always returns null.

```
async function getData(userId) {
  let documentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
  let params = {
    TableName: 'mytable',
    Key: {
      user_id: userId
    }
  };
  let result = await documentClient.get(params).promise();
  console.log(result);
  return result;
}

module.exports.handler = async event => {
  let test = getData('test');
  return { statusCode: 200, body: test };
};
```

My DynamoDB table looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FM8fE.png).

Any idea?

Comment: Don't you need to `await` for your getData?, ` let test = await getData('test');`

Comment: You're right! I now made the getData function a non async function and moved the await from the result to the getData function call and now it's working. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: No problem. If you don't mind, I will make an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The solution was to `await` for the `getData`:

```
module.exports.handler = async event => {
  let test = await getData('test');
  return { statusCode: 200, body: test };
};
```